# How to code density matrix in python?

Tags: programming

how to do this in python using for loop $\rho = \sum_i p(x)|x\rangle\langle x|$ where $X = {x1,x2,....}$ and $P = {p1,p2,p3...}$ i have tried this loop but tis not working

```
for x,y in zip(prob,kets):

  sum += x * np.outer(y,y) 
  print(sum)
```

Comment: Does the indentation(second line) look ok? It seems off... could that be the reason?

Comment: Avoid using "sum" as a variable name because Python has a built-in function with that name. You may use "_sum" instead

Comment: If you don't understand what |aXa| means, then you could ask that here; but if you understand what it means and you don't know how to do it in Python, I don't see why you wouldn't just ask the question on StackOverflow. I have plenty of times tried to keep questions like this left "open" and was outnumbered by the community, that seems to just not want "pure programming" questions here. So that's why the question got closed, sorry!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this question is *appropriate* here in this community...

Regarding to the question, it seems like what you have written should work... unless the way you define `x,y` and `sum` have issues. And as one of the comment pointed out, `sum`, is a built-in function in python so avoid to use it. So here is an example that might help:

```
import numpy as np 
zero = np.matrix([1,0])
one = np.matrix([0,1])
kets = [zero, one]
probs = [1/3, 2/3 ]
matrix = np.zeros( (2,2))
for x,y in zip(kets, probs):
    matrix += y*np.outer(x, x.conj())
print(matrix)
```

ouput

```
[[0.33333333 0.        ]
 [0.         0.66666667]]
```

which is what you expected.

Comment: I think in the for loop you want `matrix += y*np.outer(x,x)`

Comment: yeah. my bad :)

Comment: I think the issue might be that `np.outer(u, v)` computes $uv^T$ even if $u$ and $v$ have complex components. Consequently, the result is not Hermitian. What we want is $uv^\dagger$ which is computed by `np.outer(u, v.conj())`. Then again, the question does not specify the actual values used, so I can't be sure.

Comment: @AdamZalcman totally... I didn't think of that... just created a simple case to show the OP but I wasn't  thinking of complex entries... (facepalm)... Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for responding, I was using $X = {x1,x2,....}$ each x1,x2.. represents an array $(0,1,2,3),(1,1,1,1)...$ then i was getting an error.  operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,2) (4,4) (2,2) .